# How do I record video from both front and back facing cameras at same time?

Tags: camera, video

How do I record video from both the front and back facing cameras at same time?

Comment: I think that the only phone that's capable of simultaneous recording from both cameras is the Galaxy S4 - If I'm not mistaken, there aren't really any apps or methods to record from both sides at the same time on other devices.

Comment: @dotVezz Interesting. so every samsung model thereafter should have that?

Comment: @BCLC I can't say for sure, but I suspect they *don't* on newer models.

Comment: @dotVezz They do on the samsung galaxy s6 edge plus :D